# ingress-nginx not working when using ingressClassName instead of kubernetes.io/ingress.class in annotations

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, nginx-ingress

I have a baremetal cluster deployed using Kubespray with kubernetes 1.22.2, MetalLB, and ingress-nginx enabled. I am getting `404 Not found` when trying to access any service deployed via helm when setting `ingressClassName: nginx`. However, everything works fine if I don't use `ingressClassName: nginx` but `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx` instead in the helm chart values.yaml. How can I get it to work using `ingressClassName`?

These are my kubespray settings for `inventory/mycluster/group_vars/k8s_cluster/addons.yml`

```
# Nginx ingress controller deployment
ingress_nginx_enabled: true
ingress_nginx_host_network: false
ingress_publish_status_address: ""
ingress_nginx_nodeselector:
  kubernetes.io/os: "linux"
ingress_nginx_tolerations:
  - key: "node-role.kubernetes.io/master"
    operator: "Equal"
    value: ""
    effect: "NoSchedule"
  - key: "node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane"
    operator: "Equal"
    value: ""
    effect: "NoSchedule"
ingress_nginx_namespace: "ingress-nginx"
ingress_nginx_insecure_port: 80
ingress_nginx_secure_port: 443
ingress_nginx_configmap:
  map-hash-bucket-size: "128"
  ssl-protocols: "TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3"
ingress_nginx_configmap_tcp_services:
  9000: "default/example-go:8080"
ingress_nginx_configmap_udp_services:
  53: "kube-system/coredns:53"
ingress_nginx_extra_args:
  - --default-ssl-certificate=default/mywildcard-tls
ingress_nginx_class: "nginx"
```

grafana helm values.yaml

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  # For Kubernetes >= 1.18 you should specify the ingress-controller via the field ingressClassName
  # See https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/04/02/improvements-to-the-ingress-api-in-kubernetes-1.18/#specifying-the-class-of-an-ingress
  ingressClassName: nginx
  # Values can be templated
  annotations:
  #  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  #  kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
  labels: {}
  path: /

  # pathType is only for k8s >= 1.1=
  pathType: Prefix

  hosts:
    - grafana.mycluster.org
  tls:
   - secretName: mywildcard-tls
     hosts:
       - grafana.mycluster.org
```

`kubectl describe pod grafana-679bbfd94-p2dd7`

```
...
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                From               Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  25m                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/grafana-679bbfd94-p2dd7 to node1
  Normal   Pulled     25m                kubelet            Container image "grafana/grafana:8.2.2" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    25m                kubelet            Created container grafana
  Normal   Started    25m                kubelet            Started container grafana
  Warning  Unhealthy  24m (x3 over 25m)  kubelet            Readiness probe failed: Get "http://10.233.90.33:3000/api/health": dial tcp 10.233.90.33:3000: connect: connection refused
```

`kubectl get svc`

```
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
grafana      LoadBalancer   10.233.14.90   10.10.30.52   80:30285/TCP   55m
kubernetes   ClusterIP      10.233.0.1     <none>        443/TCP        9d
```

`kubectl get ing` (no node address assigned)

```
NAME      CLASS   HOSTS                    ADDRESS   PORTS     AGE
grafana   nginx   grafana.mycluster.org             80, 443   25m
```

`kubectl describe ing grafana` (no node address assigned)

```
Name:             grafana
Namespace:        default
Address:
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
TLS:
  mywildcard-tls terminates grafana.mycluster.org
Rules:
  Host                    Path  Backends
  ----                    ----  --------
  grafana.mycluster.org
                          /   grafana:80 (10.233.90.33:3000)
Annotations:              meta.helm.sh/release-name: grafana
                          meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
Events:                   <none>
```

`kubectl get all --all-namespaces`

```
NAMESPACE        NAME                                                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
default          pod/grafana-b988b9b6-pxccw                                        1/1     Running   0          2m53s
default          pod/nfs-client-nfs-subdir-external-provisioner-68f44cd9f4-wjlpv   1/1     Running   0          17h
ingress-nginx    pod/ingress-nginx-controller-6m2vt                                1/1     Running   0          17h
ingress-nginx    pod/ingress-nginx-controller-xkgxl                                1/1     Running   0          17h
kube-system      pod/calico-kube-controllers-684bcfdc59-kmsst                      1/1     Running   0          17h
kube-system      pod/calico-node-dhlnt                                             1/1     Running   0          17h
kube-system      pod/calico-node-r8ktz                                             1/1     Running   0          17h
kube-system      pod/coredns-8474476ff8-9sbwh                                      1/1     Running   0          17h
kube-system      pod/coredns-8474476ff8-fdgcb                                      1/1     Running   0          17h
kube-system      pod/dns-autoscaler-5ffdc7f89d-vskvq                               1/1     Running   0          17h
kube-system      pod/kube-apiserver-node1                                          1/1     Running   0          17h
kube-system      pod/kube-controller-manager-node1                                 1/1     Running   1          17h
kube-system      pod/kube-proxy-hbjz6                                              1/1     Running   0          16h
kube-system      pod/kube-proxy-lfqzt                                              1/1     Running   0          16h
kube-system      pod/kube-scheduler-node1                                          1/1     Running   1          17h
kube-system      pod/kubernetes-dashboard-548847967d-qqngw                         1/1     Running   0          17h
kube-system      pod/kubernetes-metrics-scraper-6d49f96c97-2h7hc                   1/1     Running   0          17h
kube-system      pod/nginx-proxy-node2                                             1/1     Running   0          17h
kube-system      pod/nodelocaldns-64cqs                                            1/1     Running   0          17h
kube-system      pod/nodelocaldns-t5vv6                                            1/1     Running   0          17h
kube-system      pod/registry-proxy-kljvw                                          1/1     Running   0          17h
kube-system      pod/registry-proxy-nz4qk                                          1/1     Running   0          17h
kube-system      pod/registry-xzh9d                                                1/1     Running   0          17h
metallb-system   pod/controller-77c44876d-c92lb                                    1/1     Running   0          17h
metallb-system   pod/speaker-fkjqp                                                 1/1     Running   0          17h
metallb-system   pod/speaker-pqjgt                                                 1/1     Running   0          17h

NAMESPACE     NAME                                TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
default       service/grafana                     LoadBalancer   10.233.1.104    10.10.30.52   80:31116/TCP             2m53s
default       service/kubernetes                  ClusterIP      10.233.0.1      <none>        443/TCP                  17h
kube-system   service/coredns                     ClusterIP      10.233.0.3      <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   17h
kube-system   service/dashboard-metrics-scraper   ClusterIP      10.233.35.124   <none>        8000/TCP                 17h
kube-system   service/kubernetes-dashboard        ClusterIP      10.233.32.133   <none>        443/TCP                  17h
kube-system   service/registry                    ClusterIP      10.233.30.221   <none>        5000/TCP                 17h

NAMESPACE        NAME                                      DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR            AGE
ingress-nginx    daemonset.apps/ingress-nginx-controller   2         2         2       2            2           kubernetes.io/os=linux   17h
kube-system      daemonset.apps/calico-node                2         2         2       2            2           kubernetes.io/os=linux   17h
kube-system      daemonset.apps/kube-proxy                 2         2         2       2            2           kubernetes.io/os=linux   17h
kube-system      daemonset.apps/nodelocaldns               2         2         2       2            2           kubernetes.io/os=linux   17h
kube-system      daemonset.apps/registry-proxy             2         2         2       2            2           <none>                   17h
metallb-system   daemonset.apps/speaker                    2         2         2       2            2           kubernetes.io/os=linux   17h

NAMESPACE        NAME                                                         READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
default          deployment.apps/grafana                                      1/1     1            1           2m53s
default          deployment.apps/nfs-client-nfs-subdir-external-provisioner   1/1     1            1           17h
kube-system      deployment.apps/calico-kube-controllers                      1/1     1            1           17h
kube-system      deployment.apps/coredns                                      2/2     2            2           17h
kube-system      deployment.apps/dns-autoscaler                               1/1     1            1           17h
kube-system      deployment.apps/kubernetes-dashboard                         1/1     1            1           17h
kube-system      deployment.apps/kubernetes-metrics-scraper                   1/1     1            1           17h
metallb-system   deployment.apps/controller                                   1/1     1            1           17h

NAMESPACE        NAME                                                                    DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
default          replicaset.apps/grafana-b988b9b6                                        1         1         1       2m53s
default          replicaset.apps/nfs-client-nfs-subdir-external-provisioner-68f44cd9f4   1         1         1       17h
kube-system      replicaset.apps/calico-kube-controllers-684bcfdc59                      1         1         1       17h
kube-system      replicaset.apps/coredns-8474476ff8                                      2         2         2       17h
kube-system      replicaset.apps/dns-autoscaler-5ffdc7f89d                               1         1         1       17h
kube-system      replicaset.apps/kubernetes-dashboard-548847967d                         1         1         1       17h
kube-system      replicaset.apps/kubernetes-metrics-scraper-6d49f96c97                   1         1         1       17h
kube-system      replicaset.apps/registry                                                1         1         1       17h
metallb-system   replicaset.apps/controller-77c44876d                                    1         1         1       17h
```

`kubectl get ing grafana -o yaml`

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: grafana
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
  creationTimestamp: "2021-11-11T07:16:12Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: grafana
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: grafana
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 8.2.2
    helm.sh/chart: grafana-6.17.5
  name: grafana
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "3137"
  uid: 6c34d3bd-9ab6-42fe-ac1b-7620a9566f62
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: grafana.mycluster.org
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: ssl-redirect
            port:
              name: use-annotation
        path: /*
        pathType: Prefix
      - backend:
          service:
            name: grafana
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Comment: How did you install Grafana chart? Could you share commands / instructions? I tried to install it using `values.yam`l (with your changes to enable Ingress) based on [these instructions](https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/grafana) but I don't have `grafana` service type LoadBalancer, instead I have ClusterIP. How did you install NGINX ingress? Could you run `kubectl get svc -n ingress-nginx` command and check if you have service `ingress-nginx-controller` type LoadBalancer with external IP?

Comment: I just downloaded the Grafana helm values.yaml, modified it to enable LoadBalancer service type, ingress, and issued `helm install grafana grafana/grafana -f values.yaml -n default`.  I installed NGINX ingress using the kubespray by enabling it in the `addons.yaml`. Added output of `kubectl get all --all-namespaces`

Comment: Could you run `kubectl get ingressclass` and paste the output? Is the Kubespray only possible solution in your case? Could you run `kubectl get ing grafana -o yaml` and check which `apiVersion` do you have?

Comment: Running `kubectl get ingressclass` returned 'No resources found'.  Provided the output of the second command.  I decided to disable the ingress-nginx addon from Kubespray and install it from helm myself and go it working.  For some reason, the ingress-nginx deployed by kubespray did not deploy a service.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Running `kubectl get ingressclass` returned 'No resources found'.

That's the main reason of your issue.

*Why?*

When you are specifying `ingressClassName: nginx` in your Grafana `values.yaml` file you are [setting your Ingress resource to use](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/04/02/improvements-to-the-ingress-api-in-kubernetes-1.18/#specifying-the-class-of-an-ingress) `nginx` Ingress class which does not exist.

I replicated your issue using [minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/), [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/) and [NGINX Ingress](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/) installed via modified [deploy.yaml file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.0.4/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml) with commented `IngressClass` resource + set NGINX Ingress controller name to `nginx` as in your example. The result was exactly the same - `ingressClassName: nginx` didn't work (no address), but annotation `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx` worked.

---

(For the below solution I'm using controller pod name `ingress-nginx-controller-86c865f5c4-qwl2b`, but in your case it will be different - check it using `kubectl get pods -n ingress-nginx` command. Also keep in mind it's kind of a workaround - usually `ingressClass` resource should be installed automatically with a whole installation of NGINX Ingress. I'm presenting this solution to understand *why* it's not worked for you before, and *why* it works with NGINX Ingress installed using helm)

In the logs of the Ingress NGINX controller I found (`kubectl logs ingress-nginx-controller-86c865f5c4-qwl2b -n ingress-nginx`):

```
"Ignoring ingress because of error while validating ingress class" ingress="default/minimal-ingress" error="no object matching key \"nginx\" in local store"
```

So it's clearly shown that there is no matching key to `nginx` controller class - because there is no `ingressClass` resource which is the "link" between the NGINX Ingress controller and running Ingress resource.

You can verify which name of controller class is bidden to controller by running `kubectl get pod ingress-nginx-controller-86c865f5c4-qwl2b -n ingress-nginx -o yaml`:

```yaml
...
spec:
  containers:
  - args:
    - /nginx-ingress-controller
    - --publish-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller
    - --election-id=ingress-controller-leader
    - --controller-class=k8s.io/nginx
...
```

Now I will create and apply following Ingress class resource:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: IngressClass
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  controller: k8s.io/nginx
```

Now in the logs I can see that it's properly configured:

```
I1115 12:13:42.410384       7 main.go:101] "successfully validated configuration, accepting" ingress="minimal-ingress/default"
I1115 12:13:42.420408       7 store.go:371] "Found valid IngressClass" ingress="default/minimal-ingress" ingressclass="nginx"
I1115 12:13:42.421487       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"default", Name:"minimal-ingress", UID:"c708a672-a8dd-45d3-a2ec-f2e2881623ea", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1", ResourceVersion:"454362", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'Sync' Scheduled for sync
```

I re-applied the ingress resource definition, I get IP address for Ingress resource.

---

As I said before, instead of using this workaround, I'd suggest installing the NGINX Ingress resource using a solution that automatically installs `IngressClass` as well. As you have chosen helm chart, it has [Ingress Class](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/charts/ingress-nginx/templates/controller-ingressclass.yaml) resource so the problem is gone. Other possible ways to install [are here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/).